# Java ,split the list of float values by 24 and get the max and assign it variables

Tags: java

an object holding the string which is a value from a json key .It is list of floats 168 values.I need to split the list by 24 and get the max of each split and assign it to 7 variables.

```
 {  
         "student": “11”,
            "scores": [1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8]
        },
    "student": “12”,
            "scores": [1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,20,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8,1,3,4,10,7,3,23,8,9,8,4,5,7,3,23,8,9,8]
    }
```

The json value returned is an object. So i need to firtst convert that into List and then traverse. I am stuck.

````
        for ( CustomObject myclassobj: customObjectList ){

            studentObj = myclassobj.getAttribute("student").getValue();
            scoreStr=  myclassobj.getAttribute("sendtime").getValue().toString();


            myclassobj.addAttribute(new Attribute( "student",studentObj));
            myclassobj.addAttribute( new Attribute( "scoreMonday",sendTimeMondayVal));
            myclassobj.addAttribute( new Attribute( "scoreTuesday",11));
            myclassobj.addAttribute( new Attribute( "scoreWednesday",11));
            myclassobj.addAttribute( new Attribute( "scoreThursday",11));
            myclassobj.addAttribute( new Attribute( "scoreFriday",11));
            myclassobj.addAttribute( new Attribute( "scoreSaturday",11));
            myclassobj.addAttribute( new Attribute( "sendtimeSunday",11));




        sendTimeRequest.addCustomObject(myclassobj);

        }```

                    "scoreSunday": 10 ,
                "scoreMonday": 8 ,
                "scoreTuesday": 12  ,
                "scoreWednesday": 14 ,
                "scoreThursday": 15 ,
                "scoreFriday":10,
                "scoreSaturday": 10

It may not be the actual value. Just that maximum of every 24 scores from 168 floats.
````

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell converting from JSON into Java is not your issue, so I will just focus on the algorithmic part. So I will assume you can get the array of numbers as an array object in JAVA

```
float[] scores = // your array loaded from json

//set up 2d array to hold the different variables
float[][] splitScores = new float[7][24]();

//splits the array into 7 portions of 24 items
for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
    splitScores[i/24][i%24] = scores[i];
}

//set up array to hold final values
float[] maxValues = new float[7]();

//leverage collections utility to easily find max value
for(int i = 0; i < maxValues.length; i++){
    ArrayList<Float> list= new ArrayList<Float>(Arrays.asList(scores[i]));
    maxValues[i] = Collections.max(list);
}

//the maxValues array should now hold the values you are looking for
```